# Flask-WTF How to populate Edit Form with relational data?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-wtforms

On many examples, I noticed to edit an existing data, form data can be output and edited using `form.populate_obj`. but i don't know if it apply in my case and still struggling to make it work. some of my form fields includes data from relational tables whose index needs to be added to this form.
how do I populate data into an existing form and update it? how do I restructure my WTF and jinja tags to populate data into the form update it since we are talking about relational data here?

here is an original Add entry form example form:

```
@projects.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def project_add():
    form = CityForm(request.form)
    form.city.choices = [('', '--- Select City ---')] + [(city.id, city.name) for city in db.session.query(City).all()]
    forms = ProjectForm()
    if forms.validate_on_submit():
        pmodel = Project(title=forms.title.data,
                         description=forms.description.data,
                         author=1,
                         posted_date=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
# Existing form loads city name and id
                         city=form.city.data)
        db.session.add(pmodel)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('New entry was successfully posted', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('deliverables.deliv_view', cid=pmodel.id))
    return render_template('ginn/deliverables_add.html', forms=forms, form=form)
```

Here is the template macro:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
<dt>
    {{ field.label }}
    <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)}}
    {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class="errors">
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
</dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Here is my form template:

```
{% block body %}

{% from '_formtool.html' import render_field %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" action="{{ url_for('projects.projects_add') }}">
    <dl>
<!-- This is an external City Form, how do I load the query to display city name from city ID? -->
        {{ render_field(form.city, id="city_select", class="city") }}
        {{ render_field(forms.title) }}
        {{ render_field(forms.description, id="textarea", class="textarea") }}
        {{ render_field(forms.started, class="datepicker") }}
    </dl>
```

Comment: Why don't you include a city field in your Project form?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to your problem would be to simply include a city field on your Project form. Creating some separate form for only one value on the fly within the view is overly complicating this task.

You could use the same list comprehension above to create the choices for that field from within the project form.

```
city_choices = [('', '--- Select City ---')] + [(city.id, city.name) for city in db.session.query(City).all()]
```

The Field in the Form:

```
city = SelectField(u'City', validators[Required()], choices=city_choices)
```

This would effectively save the foreign key of city into that field in the database.